# Rails user registration using Twitter / Facebook / Google?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, oauth

Is Devise a good option? Another extension?  Roll my own as per [OAuth in Rails - google, twitter, facebook, connect for login like stackoverflow login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566239/oauth-in-rails-google-twitter-facebook-connect-for-login-like-stackoverflow)?

Comment: i would think devise + oauth will do the job

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can go with Devise in combination with Omniauth or use Omniauth on its own building your own authentication. You need to decide whether you want local+remote sign-up or remote sign-up only. I did both recently and wrote articles about it:

- Devise + Omniauth: http://communityguides.heroku.com/articles/11
- Omniauth, includes full code on Github: http://communityguides.heroku.com/articles/16

(Links updated 15.12.2012)

Edit: Regarding local sign-up - you might use myopenid as a replacement and send users over there if they do not have or do not want a Twitter/FB/Google account...

Comment: Nice guides, thanks for the links.  I'm going to go with remote sign-up only for the moment, not sure I need local sign up.

Comment: Thank you! I'm doing the same with a side project right now, that's why I wrote Omniauth pure.

Comment: Sorry, domain expired, the content is still here: communityguides.heroku.com

Comment: Broken links... I can't even access communityguides.heroku.com

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend Devise (1.2 or newer) with OmniAuth.  I have been successful in using that combination to enable single sign-on from a Rails application to GitHub, and it's fairly trivial to add support for additional providers.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3A-Overview